# Does a topological space contain the closed sets?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

I am confused concerning the relation between closed sets and a topological space.
I know that a topological space is mostly defined in terms of open sets via the underlying topology and ist requiered properties. The sets defining the topology are then called open sets.

Given the de Morgan laws one could restate this in terms of closed sets. But this will then necessarily imply that the closed sets define the topology and thus the topological space which contains them. That the topological space will contain both open and closed sets makes me totally confused.

I know that one of the differences between a sigma algebra and a topological space is precisely this: through the complementation the sigma algebra contains also the closed sets whereas the topological space does not.

Can somebody help me clarify this confusion ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Isn't this a variant of the old member/subset confusion?

A topological space is a set $X$ together with a topology $\tau$ being the set of open subsets of $X$. The topology **contains** open sets - that is the set themselves are members of the topology. The set $X$ on the other hand has open sets as **subsets** (but the open sets are them selves not members of $X$). Of course there are closed sets as well that are subsets of $X$ and at least some of them are members of $\tau$ as well (namely $X$ and $\emptyset$).

Since closedness is defined in terms of openness we **could** have defined topological spaces instead using a set $X$ together with a topology $\phi$ being the closed subset of $X$ - we would then have slightly different rules about $\phi$ than the normal definition. But we don't normally do this (but it could perhaps be an excercise to define topological space this way and then prove that it's essentially equivalent to the standard definition).

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your doubt. If $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space, then $\tau$ is (by definition) the set of open subsets of $X$. And each element of $\tau$ is a subset of $X$. On the other hand$$\{X\setminus A\,|\,A\in\tau\}\tag{1}$$is the set of *closed* subsets of $X$ (by definition of closed subset). And the elements of $(1)$ are also subsets of $X$. I hope that this helps.

Answer (score 1):

$O$ is a open set if and only if $O^c$ is a closed set. We take complement relative to the topological space, for example, if $X$ is the topological space, and $G\subset X$, you consider $G^c=X\setminus G$. This is, yes, the closed sets lies in the topological space, NOT (in general) in the topology.

Being rigours, a topological space $(X,\tau)$ (generally it is used to say that $X$ is the topological space, forgetting tau) is a set $X$ with a subset of the power set of $X$, namely $\tau$ with certain properties. And you say that the elements of $\tau$ are open sets of $X$.

Example: Let $X=\{0,1\}$, and $\tau=\{\emptyset, \{0\},X\}$, then we have that $\tau$ define a topology on $X$ (prove it). Note that que closed sets in this case are $\{\emptyset,\{1\},X\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I think I see your problem:

> "I know that a topological space is mostly defined in terms of open
>   sets via the underlying topology"

The word "definition" and "defined" is ambiguous.  Here is an anology:

A triangle is defined by its three sides.

We may define a triangle by one side and the two angles adjacent to it.

Those sentences are both true but seem contradictory.

A triangle has $!6!$ components three sides, three angles.  But if we have three of those components we can (usually) determine completely the entire triangle.

But we *classify* a triangle by its three sides.

The same it true of a topology.

A topological space is a set, and an assignment of all possible subsets to either open, closed, both or neither so that the assignment conforms to specific conditions.

We *classify* a topological space by a class of subsets that are stated to be open.  From that class we can determine completely and unambiguously, what status (open, closed, both, or neither) *all* subsets of the topological space are.

So we say $(G, \tau)$ is a topology where $G$ is a set, and $\tau$ is a list of open subsets.

Okay, suppose we have a set $G$ and $\rho$, a list of *closed* subsets.  Can we create a topology from this?  Of course!  If $\rho$ is a list of *closed* subsets* then $\tau = \{L^c| L \in \rho\}$ will be the bases list of *open* subsets.

So the topology that we created with $G$ and $\rho$ is $(G, \tau =\{L^c| L \in \rho\})$.

There's absolutely nothing strange about this.  The topology was *created* by us knowing its *closed* subsets, but the topology is still a set and a class of *open* sets.  It's just that the open sets are the *compliments* of the closed sets.  Not the closed sets themselves.

======

"The sets defining the topology are then called open sets."

That's sort of a weird and backward way of looking at it.  The topology is *distinguished* and *recognized* by which of its subsets are open.  But we can *define* the topology in any dang way we want--- so long as the definition necessarily means precisely *those* subsets are the subsets that are open.

So a set is closed if and only if it's complement is open.  So if we chose to define the topology by listing the *closed* sets we'd get the same result.  The topology's open sets can be determined by the compliment of the closed sets.

But we wouldn't call those defining sets *open* sets.  We'd call them *closed* sets because they were defined to *be* the closed sets.

"That the topological space will contain both open and closed sets makes me totally confused."  Topologies *always* contain both open and closed sets.  That's not a big deal.

Okay, let's do an example.  Let $X = \{1,2,3,4\}$.  It has $16$ subsets.  And let $\tau$ = $\{\{2\}, \{1,3\}\}$ that means the open sets will be $X, \emptyset, \{2\}, \{1,3\}, \{2\}\cup \{1,3\} = \{1,2,3\}$.  And the closed sets will be the complements of those $X, \emptyset, \{1,3,4\}, \{2,4\} ,\{4\}$. The remaining 8 sets, $\{1\},\{3\},\{1,2\}, \{1,4\},\{2,3\},\{3,4\}\{1,2,4\},\{2,3,4\}$ are neither open nor closed.

Now we could just as easily *define* the topology by listing the *closed* sets.  We'll call the base of *closed* sets $\rho$. So we can define a topology via $\rho = \{\{1,3,4\},\{2,4\}\}$.  From this we would conclude the closed sets are $X,\emptyset,\{1,3,4\},\{2,4\}, \{1,3,4\} \cap \{2,4\} = \{4\}$.  We'd take the complements to find the open sets.  $X, \emptyset, \{2\},\{1,3\},\{1,2,3\}$. The remaining 8 sets, $\{1\},\{3\},\{1,2\}, \{1,4\},\{2,3\},\{3,4\}\{1,2,4\},\{2,3,4\}$ are neither open nor closed.

This is the exact same topology as it has the *exact* same open, closed, both and neither subsets.

ADDENDUM

In light of precise definitions:

Let $X$ be a set:  Let $\tau$ be a list of subsets of $X$ so that: 1) $X, \emptyset \in \tau$.  ii) for any $U, V \in \tau$ then $U\cap V \in \tau$ , iii) for any $\phi \subset \tau$ then $\cup_{U \in \phi} U \subset \tau$.

We say that $\tau$ is ***a topology on $X$***.

Now let $\rho$ be a list of subset of $X$ so that 1) $X, \emptyset \in \rho. ii) for any $U, V \in \rho $U\cup V \in \rho$ , iii) for any $\phi \subset \rho$ then $\cap_{U \in \phi} U \subset \rho$

We set and $\rho$ is  ***a notology on $X$***.

Exercise:  It can be verified that $\tau$ is a topology on $X$ if and only if $\{U^c| U \in \tau\}$ is a notology on $X$ (and vice versa).

Now a ***topological space*** $\langle X, \tau\rangle$ is the set $X$ and a topology $\tau$ on it, with the understanding that the $U\in \tau$ have the property of being "open".  The $V \in \{U^c|U\in \tau\}$ have the property of being "closed".  And all other subsets have neither property.

ANd let's say  a ***notological space*** $\rangle X, \rho\langle$ is the set $X$ and a notology $\rho$ on it, with the understanding that the $U\in \rho$ have the property of being "closed".  The $V \in \{U^c|U\in \rho\}$ have the property of being "open".  And all other subsets have neither property.

Notice that notological space $\rangle X, \rho\langle$ and the topological space $\langle X, \{U^c|U \in \rho\} \rangle$ are the exact same construct!

That really is all the comment is saying.

Comment: Thanks. To be honest, i got more confused now than i was before. The set X of course contains both open and closed sets, but not the topologies which you are implicitly also admitting. And yet the two topologies you are giving are not the same, they are totally different, since they are not equal, but you are claiming '' This is the exact same topology ''. What do you exactly mean by ''Topologies always contain both open and closed sets'' ? As i understand it, Instead of topology i would write ''the set X''.

Comment: Okay, I see your confusion.  You are defining "topology" to mean "set of open sets".  Okay, then.  $\rho$ is the list of *closed* sets.  So $\rho$ itself is not a topology.  But we can use $\rho$ to create a topology by figuring out what the open sets must be.  The topology that $\rho$ creates is $\tau$.  $\rho$ creates the topology $\tau$.

Comment: The two topologies are both $(X, \tau)$.  The only difference is that in the first case we were *given* $\tau$.  In the second case we were given $\rho$, class of *closed* sets, and we had to use $\rho$ to figure out what $\tau$ is.

Comment: "And yet the two topologies you are giving are not the same, they are totally different"  How do you figure they are different?  Then both have X,∅,{2},{1,3},{1,2,3} as open sets.  They both have X,∅,{1,3,4},{2,4},{4} as closed sets.  They are both the topology:  ({1,2,3,4}, {{1,3}{2}}).

Comment: Thanks again.  I think one should unambigoulsly write the topology $ \tau $ as being $ {X, \emptyset, \{2\},\{1,3\},\{1,2,3\} } $ given it's definition and aiming at avoiding confusion. If you meant $ \rho $ ( a set of closed subsets of X) only serves to create the topology $ \tau $ then it gets clearer. But now we get into a new difficulty: since the complementation is not permissive in defining a topology, only the result of the complementation process is geting acces into the topology $\tau$ and thus closed sets are not part of the topology $\tau$. Do you agree ?

Comment: Um... I'm not sure.  My understanding, maybe wrong, was that $\tau$ needn't be all open sets but just the bases of the open sets, i.e. any union of sets in $\tau$ and finite intersections of such resulting open sets, and the empty set is derived.  Also, maybe wrong, I was referring to 
"the topology" as the topological space, i.e. the "universal set" with the a notion of how to determine the status of the subsets.  Of course, a definition of "topology" as you define it: A set of sets so that the empty set is included as are an arbitrary of finite intersections of sets in it; would also work.

Comment: Ah, I was mistaken. Slightly.  $X$ is a master space.  $\tau$ is a list of subsets of $X$ so that X, null set, and any union of finite intersections of sets in $\tau$ are also in $\tau$.  To is called "the topology *on X* (it can't be a topology in itself) and $X$ with $\tau$ is the "topological space".  Technically the sets of $\tau$ by themselves are not open or closed or any thing but in reference to the *space* they are all the open sets *of the space*.  (and so $\rho$; the set of complements, will be all the closed sets of the space.)  But this is really just semantics at this point.